# Where are the points of $\{z^{z}\in \mathbb{R}|z\in\mathbb{C}\}$?

Tags: complex-numbers, graphing-functions

I was curious to find out when, given $z_1,z_2\in \mathbb{C}$, I have that $z_1^{z_2}\in \mathbb{R}$ or $z_1^{z_2}\in \mathbb{I}$, where $\mathbb{I}$ is the set of imaginary numbers.

So I used the exponential notation and Euler's formula to obtain
\begin{align}
z_1^{z_2}&=r\exp(i\theta z_2)\\
&=r\exp(i\theta (a+ib))\\
&=r\exp(-\theta b)\exp(i\theta a)\\
&=r\exp(-\theta b)(\cos(\theta a) + i\sin (\theta a)).
\end{align}

Then, by the sine and the cosine, I concluded that
\begin{align}
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
z_1^{z_2} &\in \mathbb{R}&\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad&\frac{\arg (z_1)}{\pi}\mathfrak{Re}(z_2) \in \mathbb{Z}\\[0.7 em]
z_1^{z_2} &\in \mathbb{I}&\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad&\frac{\arg (z_1)}{\pi}\mathfrak{Re}(z_2)+\frac{1}{2} \in \mathbb{Z}.
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{align}

First question: Is there any error in my conclusion?

Second question: If I take $z\in \mathbb{C}$, how can I visualize where are the values of $z$ such that $z^z\in \mathbb{R}$? What does it look like on the complex plane? I don't know how to plot something like that.

Comment: If the answer below was helpful to you, then you should [upvote](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) and [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it. It is a way to show that you have found the answer to your question and it shows your appreciation. Now it seems like you still need help. For more information [read this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

To answer your first question: No there is no error in your solution.

Now to answer: "What does $\{z\in \mathbb C\mid z^z\in \mathbb R\}$ look like?"

Well, it does not look very pretty. If we write $\arg(z)=\theta$, then $\Re(z)=r\cos \theta$. Rewriting what you found, this means that  $$z^z\in \mathbb R\iff\frac{\theta}{\pi}r\cos\theta\in\mathbb Z\iff r=\left\vert\frac {k\pi}{\theta\cos\theta}\right\vert,$$ 
for some $k\in \mathbb Z$. (Note that we may assume $k>0$ without loss of generality.)

The best idea I have to get an idea of what this looks like is just plot it for different values of $k\in\mathbb Z$. Here are the plots in WolframAlpha for [$k=1$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?lk=3&i=polar+plot+r%3D%7C1pi%2F(theta*cos+%5Btheta%5D)%7C) and [$k=3$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?lk=3&i=polar+plot+r%3D%7C3pi%2F(theta*cos+%5Btheta%5D)%7C).

All of these plots depict points $z\in \mathbb C$, for wich $z^z\in \mathbb R$. If you draw all those plots (thus for all $k\in\mathbb Z_{\geq0}$) on the same sheet, then you will see $\left\{z\in\mathbb C\mid z^z\in\mathbb R\right\}$ appear.

As I said, this will not be "pretty".